# accessing objects within object and object/functions

Tags: javascript

```
var test = {
  var1: {varx: null, vary: null},
  method1: {
    submeth1: function (x) {
      this.var1.varx = x'
    }
    submeth2: function() {
      return this.var1.varx;
    }
  },
  get_varx: function () {
    return this.var1.varx;
  }
}
test.method1.submeth1('my new value'); // the value
console.log(test.method1.submeth2());  // null
console.log(test.get_varx()); // null
```

---

why is it returning null? how do i get and set the object?

please help.. thanks..

Comment: this.var1.varx = x' <- need ";" here i guess

Comment: this.var1.varx = x' remove `'` from this line and add `;` at the end of line.

Comment: There are several issues with this code. 2 syntax errors (just lint the code to find them) and various scoping issues. `this.var1` will be undefined when calling `test.method1.submeth2` since the `this` value inside `submeth2` will be `method1`. You could solve the problem by doing the call like `test.method1.submeth2.call(test, 'some value');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check your code before submit, two syntax errors(missing ' and ,)

```
    submeth1: function (x) {
      this.var1.varx = x'
    }
```

to

```
    submeth1: function (x) {
      this.var1.varx = 'x'
    },
```

The reason is, `this` in your code `this.var1.varx = 'x'` references `test.method1`, rather than `test`, so if you define `var1: {varx: null, vary: null}` in your `test.method1`, `console.log(test.method1.submeth2())` will not give null result (advice: use chrome to debug)

```
<script>
var test = {
  var1: {varx: null, vary: null},
  method1: {
    var1: {varx: null, vary: null},
    submeth1: function (x) {
      this.var1.varx = 'x'
    },
    submeth2: function() {
      return this.var1.varx;
    }
  },
  get_varx: function () {
    return this.var1.varx;
  }
}
test.method1.submeth1('my new value'); // the value
console.log(test.method1.submeth2());  // null
console.log(test.get_varx()); // null
</script>
```

Comment: by the way, how do i access varx of test in submeth1 or submeth2 method?